# How do I setup a network peering connection from multiple GCP projects to the same MongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, networking, google-cloud-platform, vpc, peer

I have 3 projects in Google Cloud Platform. All have the default VPC Network, subnets etc. I have successfully peered a single project with a MongoDB Atlas cluster. However if I want to peer a second project it is not possible as there are overlapping subnet IP address ranges, since they are all created with the same default values.

What options do I have?

Can I use a Shared VPC network for all three GCP project and peer that with MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: The only option is to create new VPCs that do not overlap.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. I've no concern over creating additional VPCs. On a related note, the default VPC has 29 subnets (covering all available regions GCP regions). When creating a custom VPC, would it be recommended to replicate this?

Comment: Creating subnets in all regions is optional. When I create VPCs that must be secure and/or are shared I tend to only create subnets in the region we deploy services. It is harder to make a mistake and deploy services in the wrong regions in the future.

Comment: I've created a new VPC with a single subnet. I've deployed my AppEngine with the new VPC in the config. I've setup the VPC peering with my MongoDb cluster. But still it won't connect. When I open up the cluster to allow any IP address the it seems to report 34.65.xxx.xxx for connections coming from GCP.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, do not post new problems in comments, create a new question. Your first problem has been solved/answered. Post a new question with details on your connection error, configuration, firewalls,, etc.

Comment: No problem. I appreciate your input. Good stackoverflow etiquette is very important. Was your first comment on this post a general comment or an answer?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, one of the required items is for you to complete a good search for information before posting a question. My comment is a suggestion to you on what to search for. I am also giving you a hint on what the answer/solution is so that you can fine-tune your search.

Comment: There were a couple of key pieces of information which the official documentation does not include, hence I resorted to stackoverflow. Thanks for your "hints".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a project and want to peer one more with the same network and subnet values , it's impossible and as per Your requirement can create a new [**VPC**](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc) and that doesn't overlap.

To create new VPC, Go to the **VPC networks** page in the **Google Cloud Console** > Create **VPC network** > Enter a Name for the **network** > Choose Custom for the **Subnet** creation mode > New **subnet** > Provide a Name for the **subnet** > **region** > **IP address range** > if you want to define a secondary range for the subnet, click **Create secondary IP range** > you can Choose whether to enable **Private Google Access** for the subnet when you create it or later by editing it > you can Choose whether to enable VPC **flow logs** for the subnet when you create it or later by editing it > click **Done** > To add more subnets, click **Add subnet** and repeat the previous steps > Choose the **Dynamic routing mode** for the VPC network > you can Choose whether the network has an **MTU** of 1460 (default) or 1500. Review the MTU information in the concepts guide before setting the MTU to 1500 > Click **Create**.